# Cannot get string representation of databricks_user

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-databricks

Having an issue retrieving the string representation of a user object via `data "databricks_group"`:

The data source:

```
data "databricks_group" "all" {
  for_each     = toset(["group1", "group2", "group2"])
  display_name = each.key
}
```

The resource:

```
resource "databricks_group" "this" {
  for_each = data.databricks_group.all
  display_name = each.key
}
```

My attempt to retrieve the users:

```
locals {
  allusers = [for group in data.databricks_group.all : group.users]
}
```

When I later iterate `allusers`, the user object appears to be `id` and not, say, "user@foo.com".

I've also tried to obtain a mapping of group -> users, and then to transpose that to have a lookup from user->group:

```
g_to_u = {for group in data.databricks_group.all : group.display_name => group.users}
u_to_g = transpose(g_to_u)
```

But again, I retrieve only long integers (assumedly the `id`).

Any ideas appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Ah, so you first create the group, then you want to retrieve the users but you are not getting the users in the local variable?

Comment: @MarkoE hmm do you suppose I this is a plan vs. apply-time issue, whereby the data is only populated on apply? I am leaning toward that.

Comment: Not really. I see a couple of issue, I'm just trying to understand what is the desired outcome, as I would probably know how to fix it and answer. I don't see a point in using the data source to read the groups and then use a resource to create the groups that you have just read as they already exist.

Comment: @MarkoE If I could boil it down, I'd say "I am unable to access the `.users` attribute in the  databricks_user data source". I know this seems ambiguous though.

Comment: Where do you want to access it, from the local variable?

Comment: Yes from the local variable - read in via the data object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, the goal is to get all the users in the required format. This should be done in the local variable. To make this work, you need the following:

```
data "databricks_group" "all" {
  for_each     = toset(["group1", "group2", "group2"])
  display_name = each.key
}

locals {
  allusers = values(data.databricks_group.all)[*].users
}
```

Since you are querying the data source using the `for_each` meta-argument, you can use the built-in `values` function [1] to fetch all the values for all the keys and then get only the required attribute.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values